# What is the best way of getting the latest record with the most recent date in oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group, oracle12c

I have searched and seen couple of solutions, I wonder which of them is the fastest. Method I suggest using something like this:

```
select *
from (select
 TBLACCOUNT.*, 
  MIN(DATETIME) over (partition by USER_ID) max_date
  from TBLACCOUNT
  where USER_ID = 1110674
)
where dateTIME = max_date
```

Statistics:

[image]

```
buffer is not pinned count  5
buffer is pinned count  6
bytes received via SQL*Net from client  618
bytes sent via SQL*Net to client    33945
calls to get snapshot scn: kcmgss   5
calls to kcmgcs 2
consistent gets 4
consistent gets from cache  4
consistent gets pin 4
consistent gets pin (fastpath)  4
CPU used by this session    2
CPU used when call started  2
DB time 2
enqueue releases    1
enqueue requests    1
execute count   2
index scans kdiixs1 1
logical read bytes from cache   32768
no work - consistent read gets  3
non-idle wait count 18
opened cursors cumulative   2
parse count (hard)  1
parse count (total) 2
parse time elapsed  1
recursive calls 1
Requests to/from client 18
session cursor cache hits   1
session logical reads   4
session pga memory  196608
sorts (memory)  3
sorts (rows)    1683
SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client   18
table fetch by rowid    5
user calls  20
workarea executions - optimal   6
```

---

Method II :

```
Select * from (
      SELECT TBLACCOUNT.*,  
             max(DATETIME) over () as Latest_Record 
      FROM TBLACCOUNT 
) 
where USER_ID = 123456 and DATETIME = Latest_Record
```

Statistics:

[image]

```
bytes received via SQL*Net from client  586
bytes sent via SQL*Net to client    33682
calls to get snapshot scn: kcmgss   3
calls to kcmgcs 4
consistent gets 7
consistent gets from cache  7
consistent gets pin 7
consistent gets pin (fastpath)  7
CPU used by this session    1
CPU used when call started  1
DB time 2
enqueue releases    1
enqueue requests    1
execute count   2
logical read bytes from cache   57344
no work - consistent read gets  5
non-idle wait count 18
opened cursors cumulative   2
parse count (hard)  1
parse count (total) 2
parse time elapsed  1
recursive calls 1
Requests to/from client 18
session cursor cache hits   1
session logical reads   7
session pga memory  196608
sorts (memory)  3
sorts (rows)    1719
SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client   18
table scan blocks gotten    5
table scan rows gotten  58
table scans (short tables)  1
user calls  20
workarea executions - optimal   6
```

---

Method III:

```
SELECT * FROM
     (Select rownum as rnum, * 
      FROM test_table 
      WHERE user_id = value 
      ORDER BY DATE_ADDED DESC)
 WHERE rnum = 1
```

Statistics:

[image]

```
buffer is not pinned count  5
buffer is pinned count  6
bytes received via SQL*Net from client  564
bytes sent via SQL*Net to client    33882
calls to get snapshot scn: kcmgss   5
calls to kcmgcs 2
consistent gets 4
consistent gets from cache  4
consistent gets pin 4
consistent gets pin (fastpath)  4
DB time 2
enqueue releases    1
enqueue requests    1
execute count   2
index scans kdiixs1 1
logical read bytes from cache   32768
no work - consistent read gets  3
non-idle wait count 18
opened cursors cumulative   2
parse count (hard)  1
parse count (total) 2
parse time elapsed  1
recursive calls 1
Requests to/from client 18
session cursor cache hits   1
session logical reads   4
session pga memory  196608
sorts (memory)  3
sorts (rows)    1683
SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client   18
table fetch by rowid    5
user calls  20
workarea executions - optimal   6
```

---

Method IV:

```
SELECT * FROM TBLACCOUNT 
  WHERE USER_ID=123456 
  ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Statistics :

[image]

```
    buffer is not pinned count  5
buffer is pinned count  6
bytes received via SQL*Net from client  527
bytes sent via SQL*Net to client    33829
calls to get snapshot scn: kcmgss   5
calls to kcmgcs 2
consistent gets 4
consistent gets from cache  4
consistent gets pin 4
consistent gets pin (fastpath)  4
CPU used by this session    3
CPU used when call started  3
DB time 28
enqueue releases    1
enqueue requests    1
execute count   2
index scans kdiixs1 1
logical read bytes from cache   32768
no work - consistent read gets  3
non-idle wait count 18
opened cursors cumulative   2
parse count (hard)  1
parse count (total) 2
parse time cpu  2
parse time elapsed  15
recursive calls 1
recursive cpu usage 2
Requests to/from client 18
session cursor cache hits   1
session logical reads   4
session pga memory  262144
sorts (memory)  3
sorts (rows)    1683
SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client   18
table fetch by rowid    5
user calls  20
workarea executions - optimal   6
```

Which one of these give the fastest access? and why?

Comment: Why not run the test cases yourself and put `SET TIME ON TIMING ON` in `SQL*Plus` to see the time taken by each query. See the `explain plan` for each and see which query is efficient.

Comment: I already used profiler to test each of these methods, the last two had the fastest performance with the least cost. How ever, i needed a a more thorough explanation on these methods, things like logical reads and other important aspects of their performance, In profiler, i cant understand everything. But a professional dba can easily spot the best one

Comment: Also you can consider the [index descending access](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#5259) if you have relevant index.

Comment: Methods I and III are logically different to methods II and VI (btw what happened to method IV?) - they can return more than one record if there is a tie for first place.

Comment: Did you check the execution plans? Did you run the statements with `set autotrace traceonly statistics` in SQL*Plus? If you did, then please post the plans and the statistics.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes I did, i'll update the question  as soon as i can

Comment: Update the question with AutoTrace logs for all 4 methods

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges - the first query is looking for min(date), while others for max(date). The second query returns 7 rows, while others return only 1 row. Anyway, look for 'consistent gets = ?' and choose the query which has the lowest value.